# Not all features are available for live transactions in PayPal

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting this note while I'm trying to make sandbox to live app. I don't have any idea about this. Please see the screenshot below and the provided link.

[image]

After clicking the **account eligibility**, it redirect to the second picture below.

[image]

Comment: I've not done this before but the instructions look self explanatory

Comment: What does it mean about "Payout up to 500 recipients in one API Call"? Is it ok to not continue with this?

Comment: It looks like it means you can pay up to 500 people in one API call. However you can't really do that unless you provide your business details . If you don't really need to do that then you can probably just ignore that part.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by `one API call`?

Comment: A single call that will perform a request to the API, for example if you use cURL then a single `curl_exec` if you're using some sort of library then a single function that sends data to PayPal

Comment: Is it necessary to enable this feature? I used laravel with this API https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK. I only have to use it when users buy some books in my website. Do I still have to enable this?

Comment: I don't think you need this for a single person transaction.

Comment: Alright. You're great. So ... what types of transaction is this for? can you give some examples?

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/mass-payout-payments

Comment: Oh I got it. You should just use it if you have two or more accounts for user to pay?

Comment: If I get it correctly you will use it if **you** need to pay many other people. Probably does not apply to you

Comment: Wow. Nice. You did it. but I cannot give you points with comments.

Comment: Is it even if you are the business? You still have this Payouts option?